# Using QGIS Vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Difference?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, differences

I'm trying to use the Vector Geoprocessing Difference Tool in QGIS to "take a bite" out of one polygon using another in another layer. The tool menu Difference icon is exactly what I'm trying to do - it shows a circle that it "taking a bite" out of the overlapping corner of a rectangle beneath it.

I've tried every combination of input in the dialog (swaping input layer and difference layer, using selected polygons, etc.) I get three results: The union of the two layers (!), all of layer one, or all of layer two. I only get results by selecting "use only selected features". When I don't "use only selected features" it simply churns away and never produces anything at all.

The dialog seems simple and straight-forward, the operation is pretty basic, so I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Is there some twist or trick to this that I'm missing?

I've looked for detailed tutorials and/or instructions, but have not found any.

Comment: Are *both* of your polygons in the same spatial reference? There could be a projection difference that QGIS can resolve to display but the clip utility can't. Try saving the clip polygons to the same spatial reference as the polygons to be clipped (differenced) before trying again.

Comment: You are absolutely, positively RIGHT on the money. I had differing CRS's for each of the two layers. I made everything uniform and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much, this was a very frustrating problem and you have solved it for me!

I'm not sure how the Stack Exchange works, but if you transfer your comment into an answer, I'll up vote it so you get cred.

Comment: I'm just glad it helped you solve your frustrating problem. Now that this post is marked as a duplicate it can't (shouldn't) be answered but now acts as a 'signpost' directing users to the original answer.